# Invalid input datetime format of value '01/12/+00201717'

Tags: product, magento2.2

When I am updating Product date for spacial price in magento 2.2.0 then i am face problem Invalid input datetime format of value '01/12/+00201717'

Comment: Get more details from here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10485

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue when one user could save and one couldn't.

If you cannot save just:

1. Click your user name on the top right in your panel
2. Enter "Account Settings"
3. Try to change "Interface Locale" to different one
   ( I change from english UK to english US)
4. Save
5. Try to save product.